# Live Tile - Queu Notification - UWP - Windows 10

Tags: c#, queue, win-universal-app, windows-10, live-tile

I implemented liveTiles on my uwp application, but in this moment I use:

`Windows.UI.Notifications.TileUpdateManager.CreateTileUpdaterForApplication().EnableNotificationQueue(true);`

to save my Tiles, but the problem are this queu only allow 5 itens. Have any other way to put in queu or another element many tiles to show in LiveTile?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: According to the document,  the maximum items of  tile is 5. If you want more than 5 items, I'm afraid there is not a method for you to put in queu.

Comment: @JaydenGu, Thanks. Yes, I need to put more than 5 items. Any suggestion?